# AspectJ is not working for non spring classes inside internal jar

Tags: java, spring, aspectj, spring-aop, aspectj-maven-plugin

I am new to AspectJ. I have a Parent.jar which contains `@Aspect` annotated class with aspect logging say MyAspect.java. This is working fine when i mention the package of Parent.jar in `MyAspect` pointcut. Parent.jar contains a child.jar as a depenendency. I would to check the same aspectj logging on the packages of child.jar. This flow is not working..

My project is Spring Boot application. I dint add any specific dependency for AspectJ.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: The question is unclear. Can you please provide some code or better explanation? Even better would be a little [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) on GitHub or so, something to make your problem reproduceable.

Comment: When you say AspectJ, you probably mean Spring AOP with @AspectJ syntax, right? Those are two completely different things